# S/MIME icon missing from OWA

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, outlook-web-app, smime

I'm trying to test S/MIME with OWA (Exchange 2010, Outlook 2010). Now my research has told me that the control must be installed first. So as someone with admin rights, open OWA, click on All Option, then Settings then the S/MIME icon and install the contorl. I also know it has to be done in IE, 32 bit. For myself and another freshly created user, it works fine. The icon is there. But I tested it with a third user, and there is no S/MIME icon. It's missing.

The fact it's there for 2 accounts says it's enabled in the Outlook Web App Mailbox policies. I even installed it on my account and it works. There is only the default policy, so it can't be the user is assigned to a policy where it's disabled. He's assigned to the same policy as me in any case.

So why do the other accounts have the icon, but the one account doesn't? Without the icon, I can't install the control.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
I ended up using an account that had the icon available. 
Then I rerquested to install S/MIME again and I did a 'save as'.

Then had user install from the owasmime.msi download.

Comment: Where can I download the file?